# EditText crashing simple calculator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to build basic calculator, but when I put a number at first edittext and hit add button, it gets crashed. 
It is fine when I add two number in both editTexts. There was no problem in that. But the problem happened when I put only one number and hit add.
It is throwing **NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""**. 
here is my basic code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 EditText num1;
EditText num2;
Button add,sub,multi,div;
TextView MyResults;
String Number1 ;//;
String Number2 ;//
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add);
    sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sub);
    multi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Multiple);
    div = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Divide);
    MyResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Number1 =num1.getText().toString();
            Number2 =num2.getText().toString();
            int mAdd1 = Integer.valueOf(Number1);
            int mAdd2 = Integer.valueOf(Number2);
            int myAdd = mAdd1+mAdd2;
            MyResults.setText(String.valueOf(myAdd));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added: "+ myAdd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });




}//end OnCreate.
```

Comment: Well yeah, it can't make an empty string into an integer. You should check if it's empty, and make it `0` if so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave an `EditText` empty

```
int mAdd2 = Integer.valueOf(Number2);
```

Will crash because a empty `String` is not a valid `Integer` (hence the `NumberFormatException`).

You could put it in a try/catch like this:

```
try {
    Number1 =num1.getText().toString();
    Number2 =num2.getText().toString();
    int mAdd1 = Integer.valueOf(Number1);
    int mAdd2 = Integer.valueOf(Number2);
    MyResults.setText(String.valueOf(myAdd));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added: "+ myAdd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //Give a toast saying the user did not enter two correct values
}
```

Or alternatively, check the value beforehand and check if nothing was entered:

```
number1 =num1.getText().toString();
number2 =num2.getText().toString();
if (number1.equals("") || number2.equals("")) {
    //Show error or set numbers to a different value
}
```

However, for this to work you must assume the user did not enter anything that isn't a valid `Integer` like a letter, for example by setting the EditText's input type to numbers.

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Thanks your alternative code works fine. and yes I did that already. Best.

Answer (score 0):

You should do validation checking for a blank edit text and not do the calculation in this case.

Instead you might take advantage of EditText's setError(CharSequence) method where you can show a message to the user why the input is not valid.